# How to enforce that there is only one `true` value in a column per names (in an enum) of another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique

I have the following structure with an enum `{ 'ready', 'set', 'go'}` on `name`:

```
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          Id          |          enabled          |          name          |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          1           |          true             |        'ready'         |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          2           |          false            |        'ready'         |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          3           |          false            |        'ready'         |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          4           |          false            |        'set'           |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          5           |          true             |        'set'           |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          6           |          true             |        'go'            |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
|          7           |          false            |        'go'            |
|----------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|
```

How can I put a constraint on it so that there will only ever be 3 `true`'s (one on `ready`, one on `set`, and one on `go`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filtered unique indexes (or as Postgres calls them ["partial indexes"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html)):

```
create unique index unq_t_name
    on t(name)
    where enabled;
```

Comment: Filtered indexes are a wonderful feature in PostgreSQL. I'm surprised more vendors _(looks over at Oracle)_ haven't implemented this feature.